# how to read a text line by line in c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I tried to read a text line by line in c++ and it was successful. The only problem is that I want the user to press the 'enter' key on the keyboard for each line to be read except the first. My code works but the first two lines are always printed at once one the same line. For example, the user enters "brands.txt" as the name of the file and the following gets printed.

> samsungapple 
>   toshiba 
>   acer

instead of:

> samsung 
>   apple 
>   toshiba 
>   acer

Could this be a compiler error or is my code wrong? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream myFile;
    string textFile;
    string line;
    string::size_type ext;
    int count = 0;

    // request and obtain the name of the text file
    cout << "Enter the name of the file including the '.txt' extension: ";
    cin >> textFile;

    myFile.open(textFile.c_str());  // open the file

    if(myFile.is_open())    // checks if the file is open and ready to be accessed
    {
        while(getline(myFile, line))
        {
            cout << line;
            count += 1;
            cin.get();
        }
    }
    myFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Could this be a compiler error or is my code wrong?" All my money that is your error. =) BTW, what does your file contain exactly? The output you want to get?

Comment: "I want the user to press the 'enter' key on the keyboard for each line to be read except the first" - why?

Comment: my file contains samsung 
apple 
toshiba 
acer

Comment: @Neil Butterworth - Because, that is what my instructor wants and my code works. The only problem is the first two lines in the text file that gets printed on the same line.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood your problem specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `cin >> textFile`, you probably type the name of the text file and then press enter. The extraction operator for `cin` leaves that new line in the stream. From the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2):

> The extraction stops if one of the following conditions are met:
>
> a whitespace character (as determined by the ctype facet) is found. **The whitespace character is not extracted.**
>
> ...

<sub>*(emphasis mine)*</sub>

So when you then go into your loop and run `cin.get()`, it's getting that newline that was left.

Since you're not outputting anything after `line` (like a newline), the words appear concatenated like that.

A solution could be to run `getline` on `cin` once before you enter the loop to make sure you clear out all the user input (`getline` will eat the trailing whitespace) ie: `getline(cin, junk)`

Comment: Or just use `getline(cin, textFile)` instead of `cin >> textFile` in the first place.

Comment: No., @BadaCorp  They are probably attacking your intelligence for not bothering to debug your code before asking a question here.

Comment: @BadaCorp It's more a work ethic thing than an intelligence thing. You didn't bother to debug your code. Logic is logic. It doesn't matter what language. What you should have done was to narrow down where the problem was. "Why is `cin.get` skipping?" would have been a decent question for someone unfamiliar with C++, but not having the slightest idea where the bug was tells me you didn't spend much time trying to isolate it.

Comment: actually, I knew the problem was with cin.get() but I didn't know I could use cin as a parameter in getLine